# How can I spell out a number in Java?

Tags: java

How can I spell out a number(double or string) in Java? for example if the user enters the number 1920.85 , then the program must display:
One thousand nine hundred twenty and 85.

Comment: You need to make an attempt at your own homework. If you run into a specific technical question while doing it, you can ask that. To start: think about how you figure out how to pronounce a number yourself.

Comment: It's not not an assignment.